# Card creation from barcode

Tags: trello, trello-cards, barcode, qr-code

Has anyone used a barcode (or QR Code) to create a Trello card? With the keyboard shortcuts I would think it could be possible to create a new card and fill out some associated information.

Has anyone tried this?

Answer (score 1):

I think it's possible, if you look at the [Trello API for writing cards](https://trello.com/docs/api/card/index.html#post-1-cards). For starters, you'd have to make your board public, and your QR code would obviously have to make a POST request.

*Kudos on an interesting idea, though; I would love to know how it turns out! Also, I would've normally posted this as a comment but I didn't have enough rep to do that*.